# React js select dropdown delay issue

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

```
<select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange} size={5}>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>

handlechange = (event) => {
 this.setstate({selectedValue:event.target.value})
}
```

I have implemented a drop down which is working fine.
Example: I type "m" character(Mango) got highlighted then I type "c" character (Coconut) got highlighted. I continuously type character "m" and "c" it got struck in either "Mango" or "Coconut" option. What is wrong with code?